# Equivalent to C# null in managed c++

Tags: c#, managed-c++

i have one Managed C++ object

```
bool Test::TestStringNumber(String^ testData)
{
   int len = testData->Length;
   if(len > 0) return true;
}
```

am using same function in C#

```
void Main()
{
    Test t = new Test()
    t.TestStringNumber(null);
}
```

but application crash. during debugging i observed in C++ it comes as 'undefined value'

ALso i tried to test testData with nullptr in c++ code, and used following code, but still same crash

```
if( testData == nullptr && String::IsNullOrEmpty( testData ))
```

*One way is to catch exception in C++ managed code and return ;

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't simply that in the C++ you don't check it for `null` before calling `->Length` ?

Comment: yeah i am doing the same code for checking nullptr

Comment: Are you calling `t.TestStringNumber(null);` in C# or C++? If it's C# you can check for `nullptr`; if it's C++ you have to check for `null`.

Comment: i am testing in C++ with 
if( testData == nullptr && String::IsNullOrEmpty( testData ))
and in C# i am using 
tt.TestStringNumber(null)

Comment: calling from C# with t.TestStringNumber(null) and Checking nullptr in C++ using if( testData == nullptr && String::IsNullOrEmpty( testData )) but it never worked always leads to exception...

Comment: @Gabe It's a managed reference (`^`), so it will never be `null` (which doesn't even exist in C++, did you mean `NULL`==0?). `nullptr` is the C++/CLI equivalent of `null` in C#.

Comment: Can you post the actual function that's failing? It doesn't even make sense to say `if( testData == nullptr && String::IsNullOrEmpty( testData ))` because if `testData == nullptr` then `IsNullOrEmpty` will always return true.

Comment: i think i resolved issue ... its at our end thanks to every body ...
wrong check in our code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool Test::TestStringNumber(String^ testData)
{
  return !String::IsNullOrEmpty( testData );
}
```

Should work just fine? Not that I see the point in your code?